# Azure API Management - OAuth server Token endpoint?

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

im currently setting up an Web API on Azure Cloud Service and want to use Azure API Management with OAuth and Azure Active Directory (AD) as Authorization Server.

My question is:
In AD I have created my application and looking in the "View Endpoints" list my endpoint for the token request is (not with original key):

https://login.windows.net/e4b3b3s1-02yt-8fw1-54i3-973aa45rd56b/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0

However, in this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-oauth2/

The format for token request is:

```
https://login.windows.net/<APPID>/oauth2/token
```

> For an Azure Active Directory OAuth 2.0 server, the Token endpoint
>   URL will have the following format, where  has the format of
>   yourapp.onmicrosoft.com.

which one should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the ones listed in AAD because they have the addition parameter specifying the version to use.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672514/given-azure-endpoint-domains-hash-versus-onmicrosoft/27672530#27672530). Use what the Active Directory Console gives you - it will work.