# Given Azure Endpoint Domains: Hash versus *.onmicrosoft

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a web app to work with Azure AD.

I'm going through the process of making the REST requests, etc., and I'm a bit confused as to the endpoint URL parameters given by AD versus those given in the [help documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks) versus what I'm given in the AD console online. On some of the documentation pages, the endpoints are given as "https://login.windows.net/[some domain].onmicrosoft/...", where on the AD console, I'm given a long hash, with no ".onmicrosoft/..." present. I'm having problems with both (something else is obviously wrong), but I can't proceed debugging that until I know which I should proceed with, so I know that this isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed confusing and not well hashed out in the documentation.

I've created a web-app that also uses Office 365 authentication with Azure AD, and I am using the hash generated by the Azure AD console for my endpoint URLs, and everything is functioning well. Whatever the AD console gives you online is correct, and will work for your particular app (the hash given is in fact replacing a .onmicrosoft domain, and will work well).

Answer (score 3):

The "hash" is actually a GUID, and is your tenant ID - the unique identifier for your Azure AD tenant.  When constructing the `login.windows.net` endpoints you can use the tenant ID and the domain name (yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com) interchangeably.

See [this post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/18/from-domain-to-tenantid/) from Vitorrio Bertocci for more details on the subject.